Similarity Solutions for the 2D Heat Equation in Polar Coordinates (with radial symmetry)
I'm attempting to solve the 2D heat equation expressed in polar coordinates, where $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = 0 $ due to radial symmetry. This simplifies the equation to $ D (u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r} u_{r}) = u_t $, where $ D $ represents the diffusivity, with boundary conditions $u(0, t) = u_0$ and $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} u(r, t) = 0$, and initial condition $u(r, 0) = 0$.
To find a similarity solution, I applied a dilation (scale) transformation:
$ z = \epsilon^a r  $,
$ s = \epsilon^b t $,
$ v = \epsilon^c u $.
Substituting these scaled variables into the equation yields:
$ D (\epsilon^{2a-c} v_{zz} + \frac{\epsilon^a}{z} \epsilon^{a-c} v_z) = \epsilon^{b-c} v_s $.
Thus, if $ 2a = b $, the PDE remains unchanged. Leveraging the combination $ zs^{-a/b} = \epsilon^a r (\epsilon^b t)^{-a/b} = r t^{-a/b} $, I define a new similarity variable $ \xi = \frac{r}{\sqrt{t}} $.
To validate this similarity variable, I employed the Finite Difference Method (FDM) to solve the original PDE and obtained solutions at different times. However, when I nondimensionalized the results using $ \xi $, the curves did not superpose, as shown in this Figure.
What have I done incorrectly? Are there alternative similarity variables or approaches I could explore?

Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4907611/find-self-similar-solution-for-the-heat-equation/4907768

@TravisWillse is $r / \sqrt{t}$ a correct similarity variable for this problem? The linear diffusion equation in 1d has the same similarity variable, shouldn't the similarity variables be different for 1d and 2d?
