Find self-similar solution for the heat equation
I would like to find solutions to the equation
$$\partial_t \phi = \partial_{rr}\phi + \frac{1}{r}\partial_r \phi - \frac{1}{r^2}\phi$$
of the form $\phi(t, r) = t^{-\gamma} g(r/\sqrt{t})$. This equation comes from the heat equation in polar coordinates for function $\psi(r, \theta) = \phi(r)e^{i\theta}$. Plugging this form of $\phi$ in the equation leads to the ODE in $\xi$
$$\frac{1}{t^{\gamma + 1}} \left( g'' + \frac{1}{\xi} g' - \frac{1}{\xi^2} g + \gamma g + \frac{1}{2}\xi g\right) = 0 \quad \text{for } \xi = \frac{r}{\sqrt t}.$$
Multiplying by $t^{\gamma + 1}$ on both sides, we get the ODE depending only on $\xi$ and $\gamma$.
I would like to find solution of this equation for specific value of $\gamma$. I managed to find a straightforward solution $g(\xi) = \xi$ for $\gamma = -1/2$. Moreover, for $\gamma = 3/2$, I managed to find the solution
$$g(\xi) = \xi e^{-\xi^2/4}.$$
Now I would like to find solution of this ODE for $\gamma$ positive and lower than $3/2$, i.e. $\gamma \in (0,3/2)$, but to be honest I don't see anything obvious. Any idea ?

How is $g = \xi$ a solution when $\gamma = 1/2$? Substituting into your ODE above yields $\xi + \xi^{2} = 0$.

Ohhhh right, my bad, it's when $\gamma = -1/2$ that $g(\xi) = \xi$. I will edit it, thank you.

In terms of $\xi := \frac{r}{\sqrt t}$ the o.d.e. should be
$$g''(\xi) + \left(\frac\xi2 + \frac1\xi\right) g'(\xi) + \left(\gamma - \frac1{\xi^2}\right)g(\xi) = 0 .$$
Changing variables via $g(\xi) := \xi e^{-\frac{\xi^2}4} h(\xi)$ and then $\zeta = \frac{\xi^2}4$ transforms the equation into Kummer's equation with parameters $\mu = \frac32 - \gamma, \nu = 2$
$$\zeta h''(\zeta) + (2 - \zeta) h'(\zeta) - \left(\frac32 - \gamma\right) h(\zeta) = 0$$
In particular, the general solution (for general $\gamma$) is
$$h(\zeta) = c_1 M_{\frac32 - \gamma, 2}(\zeta) + c_2 U_{\frac32 - \gamma, 2}(\zeta),$$
where $M_{\mu, \nu}(z) = {}_1 F_1(\mu; \nu; z)$ is Kummer's function and $U_{\mu, \nu}$ is Tricomi's function. Back-substituting gives that the corresponding solutions to the original equation are:
$$\phi(r, t) = \frac{r}{4 t^{\frac12 + \gamma}} e^{-\frac{r^2}{4 t}}\left[c_1 M_{\frac32 - \gamma, 2}\left(\frac{r^2}{4 t}\right) + c_2 U_{\frac32 - \gamma, 2}\left(\frac{r^2}{4 t}\right)\right] .$$
For particular values of $\gamma$, $M_{\frac32 - \gamma, 2}$ and $U_{\frac32 - \gamma, 2}$ can be expressed in terms of perhaps more familiar functions. For example, for $\gamma = \frac32$, the general solution is
$$h(\zeta) = a + b \left(\frac{e^\zeta}\zeta + \operatorname{Ei}_1(-\zeta)\right),$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}_1$ denotes an exponential integral function, which subsumes the example in the question statement. (More generally, for strict half integers $\gamma \geq \frac 32$ there is a polynomial solution $h(\zeta)$ given by a generalized Laguerre polynomial.)

For $\gamma = \frac12$, the general solution is
$$h(\zeta) = \frac1\zeta (a + b e^\zeta) ,$$
and back-substituting (and absorbing constants) gives
$$\phi(r, t) = a \cdot \frac1r \exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{4 t}\right) + b .$$

For $\gamma = 1$ (and for integer $\gamma$ more generally), we can express the general solution in terms of modified Bessel functions:
$$h(\zeta)
= e^{\frac\zeta2}
\left[
a \left(I_0\left(-\frac\zeta2\right) + I_1\left(-\frac\zeta2\right)\right) + \left(K_0\left(-\frac\zeta2\right) - K_1\left(-\frac\zeta2\right)\right)
\right] .$$


